# When to wrap JS variable in quotes

Tags: javascript, function, quotes

I have the following JS which is working but I'm confused by why I need to wrap the variable func in quotes.  Could someone explain?

```js
function CustomPrompt(){
 this.render = function(dialog,func){
   var winW = window.innerWidth;
   var winH = window.innerHeight;
   var dialogoverlay = document.getElementById('dialogoverlay');
   var dialogbox = document.getElementById('dialogbox');

   dialogoverlay.style.display = "block";
   dialogoverlay.style.height = winH+"px";
   dialogbox.style.left = (winW/2) - (550 * .5)+"px";
   dialogbox.style.top = "100px";
   dialogbox.style.display = "block";

   document.getElementById('dialogboxhead').innerHTML = '&nbsp';
   document.getElementById('dialogboxbody').innerHTML = dialog;
   document.getElementById('dialogboxbody').innerHTML += '<br><input id="prompt_value1"  >';
  
   document.getElementById('prompt_value1').focus();

//HERE'S THE LINE I'M CONFUSED BY
//*******************************
   document.getElementById('dialogboxfoot').innerHTML = '<button onclick="Prompt.ok(\''+func+'\')">OK</button> <button onclick="Prompt.cancel()">Cancel</button>';
    
 }

 this.cancel = function(){
   document.getElementById('dialogbox').style.display = "none";
   document.getElementById('dialogoverlay').style.display = "none";
 }
 this.ok = function(func){
   var prompt_value1 = document.getElementById('prompt_value1').value;
   window[func](prompt_value1);
   document.getElementById('dialogbox').style.display = "none";
   document.getElementById('dialogoverlay').style.display = "none";
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `func` variable seems to be a string which identifies a function attaches to the global `window` object which you call with `window[func](prompt_value1);` in your `ok` function.

`func` needs to be sent as a string, since *it's a key* on the window object.

If you were to remove the qoutes in your example the onclick method of the button would try to send the value of your `func` variable in the current scope. Since `func` is declared in your function scope you would not be able to access it. Instead the variable value is inlined.

**This example inlines the variable *place***

```js
function hello(place) {
  console.log(place);
}
function iHaveMyOwnScope() {
  var place = "world"; // this is in my scope
  var container = document.getElementById('container1');
  container.innerHTML = '<button onclick="hello(\''+place+'\')">Hello1</button>';
}
iHaveMyOwnScope();
```

```html
<div id="container1"></div>
```

**This example tries to access the variable *place* via global scope**

Since `place` isn't defined in a global scope it is not accessible.

```js
function hello(place) {
  console.log(place);
}
function iHaveMyOwnScope() {
  var place = "world"; // this is in my scope
  var container = document.getElementById('container1');
  container.innerHTML = '<button onclick="hello(place)">Hello2</button>';
}
iHaveMyOwnScope();
```

```html
<div id="container1"></div>
```

**This example programatically creates the button and attaches the event handler inside the function scope**

```js
function hello(place) {
  console.log(place);
}
function iHaveMyOwnScope() {
  var place = "world"; // this is in my scope
  var container = document.getElementById('container1');
  
  var button = document.createElement('button')
  button.innerHTML = 'Hello3'
  button.addEventListener('click', function() {
    // Here we can access the place variable
    // since this handler is defined in the functions scope
    hello(place)
  }, false)
  
  // Add button to container
  container.appendChild(button);
}
iHaveMyOwnScope();
```

```html
<div id="container1"></div>
```

Comment: if I say var func='newToDo' , console.log(func) -> newToDo.  If I then say Prompt.ok(func); it works fine. so since the html is onclick="Prompt.render('Input a new ToDo:','newToDo')" why do I have to rewrap newToDo in quotes?

Comment: @DCR I updated my answer. If you remove the qoutes in your post example the `func` variable would be used in a scope in which it is not declared. It is part of the `render` function scope.

Comment: thanks for your answer  but I don't understand.  Is there a reference or a tutorial that could walk me through this?

Comment: @DCR I added some examples that might help you understand.

Comment: thanks for your help.  Can you point to a reference that explains scope and inlining a variable?